# Dynamically using same method in multiple web service references?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, methods

In c# .Net Framework 4.5 (Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5), I'm trying to define a service variable at runtime for which webservice to use. Each webservice (there are many) are all defined the same except for the endpoint url but the credentials will not cross over to authenticate. The below condition is menial to simplify the issue at hand. The following code gives the error: Cannot implicitly convert type `WebService2.Service` to `WebService1.Service`.

What I've tried: calling functions to return the proper service but the parameters or assignment all require a specific type.

```
var service = new WebService1.Service();
service = new WebService2.Service();
```

I want to be able to use the variable `service` in the rest of the program without having to duplicate code everywhere for using the many web service references.

Comment: Are these WCF services?

Comment: Do the different web services have the same methods / signature?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking to do, you would need a common interface between the two services so you could inject whichever service you wish to use.

```
public class WebService1 : IWebService {...service code} 
public class WebService2 : IWebService{...service code}
public interface IWebService{...service methods you will be calling}
```

Then you could do the following.

```
IWebService service = new WebService1.Service();
service = new WebService2.Service();
```

Comment: Are you indicating to redefine the internal methods of the webservices for IWebService{}? The webservices are from a 3rd party, the code is not accessible.

Comment: What I was suggesting is the same implementation that Cam Bruce has also suggested.

Comment: WebService1 and WebService2 are already defined under References - WebService for the project. I can't rewrite the 3rd party code for those. ?? The "servcice" use is already throughout an existing program but now it needs to be able to use either WebService1 or WebService2 at runtime without rewriting the existing "service" code. I was hoping to define which it uses at runtime when the program starts.

Comment: In this example, the 'service methods you will be calling' are already defined in the WebService1 and WebService2 with the same names.

Comment: Hmm that does make it more difficult. The Third Party should have supplied you with a common interface if they designed there services to be interchangeable.

Comment: Without being able to change the WebService to implement an interface, you may have to write a wrapper around each web service and then have the wrappers implement a common interface. How many methods are you calling on this service? You could also create a class that you use instead of the service class that could switch between service references to call the service you want.

Comment: The "...service code" is eluding me. I don't have a clue what should go there. I think I've got "service" working but not its properties. When I try to set service.Credentials = credentialCache; then the error on ".Credentials" is IWebService does not contain a definition for Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the different services share the same method names, you can create an interface that all of the services implement by using the interface

**IMyService.cs**

```
interface IMyService
{
     void MyMethod(string filter);
}
```

**MyWebServiceImplementation.cs**

```
public class MyWebServiceImplementation : IMyService
{
    public void MyMethod(string filter);
}
```

**MySecondWebServiceImplementation.cs**

```
public class MySecondWebServiceImplementation : IMyService
{
    public void MyMethod(string filter);
}
```

**MyImplemetationCode.cs**

```
//Use different services from same variable

IMyService service = new MyWebServiceImplementation();
service.MyMethod("filter");
service = new MySecondWebServiceImplementation();
service.MyMethod("another filter");
```

Comment: Yes, they have the exact same methods. When pasting this code, the first line that starts with service has an error "is a field but used like a type". The line after that says MySecondWebServiceImplementation() "Method must have a return type."

Comment: the implementation code should be in a separate class - wherever you are calling the web service from. see updated answer

Comment: Gotcha on that part but can you insert the WebService1 and WebService2? I'm not doing something right to get it working. My code now has an error on serivce.Credentials = credentialCache; "MyWebServiceImplementation does not contain a definition for Credentials.

Comment: Ah, I see Credentials is coming from my webservice. Does that indicate it wasn't set to service correctly?     public class MyWebServiceImplementation : IMyService
    {
        public void MyMethod(string filter) {var service = new WebService1.Service(); }
    }

Comment: You will have to add the properties of the web service that you need onto the interface in order to access them via the interface.

Comment: The properties are already in WebService1 and WebService2 with the same property/method names.

Comment: The interface needs to have the properties in it's signature in order to share the different service implementations